# How to make Navbar fixed on mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I feel like this should be easier for me to solve but for some reason I can't get it to work right.

I would like the Navigation to be fixed at the top on mobile. What am I missing?

http://www.valleygolfwillmar.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to modify this rule

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    #header {
        position:fixed; /** Change to fixed **/
    }
}
```

currently it is set to relative on mobile

**Edit** Code updated with appropriate class

Comment: @DanGraves updated the code try now, If it still doesnt work add `!important` to make sure its not being overwritten elsewhere

Comment: Actually that opened up a new can of worms. Now the top padding is messed up on mobile. Maybe I'll just say screw it, this is a non paying job for a friend, hence why I opted to use a premade template

Comment: You can always adjust the padding as needed by adjusting the wrapper on mobile as well

`body #wrapper {padding-top: 60px;} /** Current height of nav **/` Which would sit in the same `@media` query